# Following the DRY principle in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, dry

I have just recently got involved in a classic ASP.NET project which contains lots of storing and reading values from the session and query strings. This could look something like the following:

```
Session["someKey"]=someValue;
```

And somewhere else in the code the value in the session is read. Clearly this violates the DRY principle since you'll have the literal string key spread out all over the code. One way to avoid this could be to store all keys as constants that could be referenced everywhere there is a need to read and write to the session. But I'm not sure that's the best way to do it. How would you recommend I best handle this so that I don't violate the DRY principle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a separate public class where you can define your constants, e.g

```
public class SessionVars
{
   public const string SOME_KEY = "someKey";
   public const string SOME_OTHER_KEY = "someOtherKey";
}
```

and then anywhere in your code you can access session variables like this:

```
Session[SessionVars.SOME_KEY]=someValue;
```

This way you can get IntelliSence and other bells and whistles.

Comment: +1 This is the pattern I tend to follow - it really helps eliminate those pesky typo bugs.

Comment: You should not use `const` in this context. `static readonly` is more appropriate (and safe).

Comment: How is that alleviating the principle of Dont Repeat Yourself? You're still writing the same 1 liner everywhere, you're just using a constant variable instead of an instance string for the key?

Comment: This is similar to what I have done previously and is probably what I would do, combined maybe with wrapping the session in a property. It removes the need to remeber the string and type it correctly, you get intellisense and there is only one place to change the key.

Comment: As far as the concern that this does not follow the DRY principle, at least it's a step forward. If you think that writing the one liner SessionVars.SOME_KEY violates DRY, then I think that is reading to much into DRY, as replied in one of the other posts.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're reading too much into DRY. I pertains more to things that could be wrapped up in a function. I.e. instead of repeating the same fives lines all over the place wrap those 5 lines in a function and call the function everywhere you need it.

What you have as an example is just setting a value in a dictionary (the session object in this case), and that is the simplest way to store and retrieve objects in it.

Comment: I wish you never inherit a project full of *magic* strings your need to maintain...

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember for the life of me where I humbly *re-purposed* this code from, but it's pretty nice:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace Project.Web.UI.Domain
{
    public abstract class SessionBase<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        private static readonly Object _padlock = new Object();

        private static string Key
        {
            get { return typeof(SessionBase<T>).FullName; }
        }

        public static T Current
        {
            get
            {
                var instance = HttpContext.Current.Session[Key] as T;

                lock (SessionBase<T>._padlock)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Session[Key] 
                          = instance 
                          = new T();
                    }
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }

        public static void Clear()
        {
            var instance = HttpContext.Current.Session[Key] as T;
            if (instance != null)
            {
                lock (SessionBase<T>._padlock)
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Session[Key] = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The idea behind it two fold.  The type created should be the only type you need.  It's basically a big strongly-typed wrapper.  So you have some object you want to keep extending information in:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()

    public string Blah1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then down the road you extend `MyClass` and you don't want to have to remember all the Key Values, store them in AppSettings or Const variables in Static Classes.  You simply define what you want to store:

```
public class MyClassSession : SessionBase<MyClass>
{ 
}
```

And anywhere in your program you simply use the class.

```
// Any Asp.Net method (webforms or mvc)
public void SetValueMethod()
{
  MyClassSesssion.Current.Blah1 = "asdf";
}

public string GetValueMethod()
{
  return MyClassSession.Current.Blah1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Erik Philips for your well-structured code. I really like it. Would it be possible to show us more clear example?

Comment: @JohnNate I'm not sure how this can be more clear.  Is there something specific that isn't clear?

Comment: Yes, I would like to see an example of applying your code in ASP.NET Web Forms

Comment: @JohnNate AFAIK it works in webforms with no modifications.  Create your `MyClass` to store your structured data in, Derive your own `MyClassSession` class from `SessionBase<MyClass>` and then use `MyClassSession` in your webforms.

Answer (score 0):

Optionally you could place the access to this session object in a base page and wrap it in a property:

```
class BasePage : Page
{
   ...
   public string MySessionObject
   {
      get
      {
         if(Session["myKey"] == null)
            return string.Empty;
         return Session["myKey"].ToString();
      }
      set
      {
          Session["myKey"] = value;
      }
   }
   ...
}
```

Here you are repeating the `myKey` string but it is encapsulated into the property. If you want to go to the extreme of avoiding this, create a constant with the key and replace the string.